# When trying to overwrite a equals method in Java, it won't compare the values only the object itself?

Tags: java, object, arraylist

In this exercise, I need to create a `equals()` method for a `Drink` class. Two drinks are the same if they have the same name and same size. I am receiving `false` from testing the method, even though I'm certain it should be `true`.

The main code:

```java
public class Drink {
    private String name;
    private double size;
    
    public Drink(String name, double size) 
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.size = size;
    }
    
    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }
    
    public double getSize()
    {
        return size;
    }
    
//I tried to stringify the double values

    public boolean equals(Drink a, Drink b){
        String q = String.valueOf(a.getSize());
        String w = String.valueOf(b.getSize());
        if(q.equals(w) && a.getName().equals(b.getName())){
            return true;
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

The tester Code:

```java
public class DrinkTester
{
    
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Drink one = new Drink("Soda", 12);
        Drink two = new Drink("Soda", 12);
        Drink three = new Drink("Soda", 20);
        System.out.println(one.equals(two));
        System.out.println(one.equals(three));
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. You've shown the code you've written, but you also need to show the program calling it, the class it's in, and explain what behaviour you are seeing. Please read [ask].

Comment: You also need to look at the signature of `Object.equals`. Have you overriden it?

Comment: See [`Object.equals(Object)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object)). And **please** use the [`@Override` annotation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Override.html).

Comment: You have overloaded `equals`, not overridden `equals`. Your `equals(Drink, Drink)` is never called, as `equals(Object)` is called..

Answer (score 0):

You need to override the equals method, if you use the
@Override annotation you'll see if you're doing it right.

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
  return (this == obj);
}
```

That is the Object one, so yours might for example look like:

```
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj) return true;
    if (obj == null || getClass() != obj.getClass()) return false;
    Drink drink = (Drink) obj;
    return this.size.equals(drink.size) 
     && this.name.equals(drink.name);
}
```

you'll also have to override your hashCode if you want your code to work optimally.

**(And i've only recently noticed that if you use Objects.hash in your overridden hashCode method, your overridden equals method won't get used, the Objects one will get used instead)**